# Replace URLConnection with other code

Tags: java, android, inputstream

I have got this code for Android to get InputStream

```
URL myURL = new URL("http://www.echo.msk.ru/interview/rss-audio.xml");
URLConnection ucon = myURL.openConnection();
InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
```

And somehow for that URL http://www.echo.msk.ru/interview/rss-audio.xml I always get an exception. But I can open that URL in browser...

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "www.echo.msk.ru": No address associated with hostname
libcore.io.GaiException: getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
Unable to resolve host "www.echo.msk.ru": No address associated with hostname
```

Is there some way to get that resource/XML in other way in Java for Android?

Thanks!

P.S. Here is my manifest xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="org.developerworks.android"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".MessageList"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="2" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> </manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a HTTP get Request using AsyncTask

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://www.echo.msk.ru/interview/rss-audio.xml");  
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
String  _response=EntityUtils.toString(resEntity); 
 Log.i(".......",_response);
```

Part of the log

```
12-29 05:13:12.313: I/.......(3830): <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
12-29 05:13:12.313: I/.......(3830): <rss version="2.0" xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd">
12-29 05:13:12.313: I/.......(3830):   <channel>
12-29 05:13:12.313: I/.......(3830):     <title>
12-29 05:13:12.313: I/.......(3830):       Горячие интервью (звук) | Эхо Москвы
12-29 05:13:12.313: I/.......(3830):     </title>
12-29 05:13:12.313: I/.......(3830):     <link>http://echo.msk.ru/interview/</link>
12-29 05:13:12.313: I/.......(3830):     <atom:link
12-29 05:13:12.313: I/.......(3830):       href="http://echo.msk.ru/interview/rss-audio.xml %>"
12-29 05:13:12.313: I/.......(3830):       rel="self"
12-29 05:13:12.313: I/.......(3830):       type="application/rss+xml"
12-29 05:13:12.313: I/.......(3830):     />
12-29 05:13:12.313: I/.......(3830):     <description>
12-29 05:13:12.313: I/.......(3830):       Эхо Москвы: Интервью
12-29 05:13:12.313: I/.......(3830):     </description>
12-29 05:13:12.313: I/.......(3830):     <image>
12-29 05:13:12.313: I/.......(3830):       <title>Горячие интервью (звук) | Эхо Москвы</title>
12-29 05:13:12.313: I/.......(3830):       <link>http://echo.msk.ru/interview/</link>
12-29 05:13:12.313: I/.......(3830):       <url>http://echo.msk.ru/img/sys/logo_print.gif</url>
12-29 05:13:12.313: I/.......(3830):       <width>121</width>
12-29 05:13:12.313: I/.......(3830):       <height>80</height>
12-29 05:13:12.313: I/.......(3830):     </image>
```